# How do I trigger a CSS keyframe animation by pressing a key on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, keyboard-events

I'm trying to create a super basic version of the Chrome offline dinosaur game. I created a CSS `@keyframes` animation to create the jumping of a character, but I can't figure out how to trigger this animation when I press the spacebar or any key on the keyboard. I've tried using the different keyboard-related `eventListeners`, and I've even tried just using a button, but none of it worked.

The last thing I tried was using JavaScript to add the class list "jumping", which is styled in CSS with the animation.

On my HTML, I just have the image of the dinosaur under the class "dino"

On CSS:

```
@keyframes jump {
  60% {
    transform: translate(0px, -25vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

.dino {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50vh;
}

.jumping {
  animation: jump 0.5s linear;
}
```

This is what I last had on my JavaScript file:

```
var jump = function(event) {
  var dino = document.querySelector('.dino');

  if (event.key == "space") {
  dino.classList.add('jumping');
  }
}
```